# Failing to search for full names while querying mysql with php

Tags: php, mysqli, concatenation

First time asking on SO. I currently am trying to search a database where the first and last names are seperate. Example:

```
player_id | first_name   | last_name  
   191         John          Smith
   192         Larry         Citizen
   193         Benjamin      Example
```

I am trying to allow users to search this list using a full name only. I currently have the following code once the user hits submit, it calls usersearch.php.

```
session_start();

include '../con.php';

$player = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE (concat(first_name,' ',last_name)) = ($player)";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "Found no-one with the name $player. <a href='../search.php'>Try Again?</a>";

} else {

    $_SESSION['selplate'] = $row['plate'];
    $_SESSION['selname'] = $row['first_name, last_name'];

    header("Location: ../profile.php?player=$player");

}
```

No matter the query it will not find users and always returns "Found no-one with the name $player. Try again?"

This was supposed to be the easy part of this project and I am pulling my hair out.

I have spent over an hour searching SO and Google to no avail so it must be my code? afaik it should work.

Comment: Show us how you do the search.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: What's player name, what name are you searching for and what record is it not finding, ( don't pretend ) I mean exactly...

Comment: Should do this with binds, but anyway, change the () for quotes - `= ($player)"` to `= '$player'"`

Comment: I wouldn't search with concat in the WHERE anyway it will prevent the query from using any indexes may have, and destroy performance.....  What about  first name misplaced with last name? things happen.  Personally I would convert the first last name to a compound Text index and do `Match( first, last ) Against ( .... )`  but be careful of names like `AL`  lol ... all I'm gonna say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need qoutes ' ' around player because its a text and  also concatinated.
if you search **Johnsmith** it will return nothing
if you search **John Smith** it will give you result, because in your concat you are adding a space between words

```
"SELECT * FROM characters WHERE concat(first_name,' ',last_name) =('".$player."')"
```

Answer (score 0):

delete the white-space from concat function in query and other thing is use `$player = str_replace(' ','',trim($_POST['name']))` instead of `$player = $_POST['name']`.

`$SQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE concat(first_name,last_name) = '".$player."'"`

i suggest `PDO` with prepared statements...

assume you are searching 'benjamin example' and query will check for 'benjamin example' so str_replace will output as `benjaminexample`.and the concated first_name and last_name will match it.

hope it help.
ignore if it sound silly.

Comment: what about `example benjamin` will it find that?

Answer (score 0):

I would change it to a fulltext index on both first and last name, change the word min on full text indexes. then I would search using  ( some guy as the name )

```
  MATCH( first, last )AGAINST('+"some" +"guy"' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```